# inline td with th using loop in PHP

Tags: php, html, web

So I have this tables on my database that I have to display as table in html. The problem is I do not know how I am going to inline my td with my th and add zero to the person who doesn't have allowance.

This is the image of my allowance table

[image: allowance table].

So far this is what i have:

```
<?php 
  error_reporting(0);
  include "./includes/connectdb.php";

  $emp = "select * from employee";
  $q = $dbhandle->query($emp);
  if($q->num_rows>0){   

  $all = "select distinct allowance from emp_allowances order by allowance     asc";
  $a = $dbhandle->query($all);
   if($a->num_rows>0) {
    while($b = $a->fetch_assoc()){
     $thallowance .= '<th>'.$b['allowance'].'</th>';
     $empallowance = $b['allowance'];

    }

  }
    while($r = $q->fetch_assoc()){

     $id= $r['id'];
     $name= $r['name'];

     $all2 = "select * from emp_allowances order by allowance asc";
     $c = $dbhandle->query($all2);
      if($c->num_rows>0){
        $tdallow='';
        while($d = $c->fetch_assoc()){
        $empid = $d['emp_id'];
        $empallowance = $d['allowance'];
        $amount = $d['amount'];

        if($empid==$id){
            $tdallow.='<td>'.$amount.'</td>';
        }
      }
     }  
        $tbody .= '<tr>
           <td>'.$name.'</td>
              '.$tdallow.'
           </tr>';
    }
  }
     $thead = '
        <thead>
        <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                '.$thallowance.'
            </tr>
        </thead>    
            ';
 ?>

   <table border=1> 
      <?php echo $thead; ?> 
   <tbody>
     <?php echo $tbody; ?>
  </tbody>
```

And from this code i got this result.

[image: output image]

Comment: In the table, for example, the only "clothing" value "500", while the result of the "clothing" column 250, and 150 is also included! Very mixed together are the values!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your while loop, try to copy it and see if works.

The `$tdarray` sets all allowances to zero, if some of them has a greater value it is set in the employee allowances loop. This way if there is no allowance for an employee there will be zero and properly inline, because the default values (zeros) are preset.

Let me know if works.

```
<?php 
  error_reporting(0);
  include "./includes/connectdb.php";

  $emp = "select * from employee";
  $q = $dbhandle->query($emp);
  if($q->num_rows>0){   


  // array that will hold key value pairs for allowances
  $tdarray = array();
  $all = "select distinct allowance from emp_allowances order by allowance     asc";
  $a = $dbhandle->query($all);
   if($a->num_rows>0) {
    while($b = $a->fetch_assoc()){
     $thallowance .= '<th>'.$b['allowance'].'</th>';
     $empallowance = $b['allowance'];
     // fill the array with keys (allowances) and default, zero values
     $tdarray[$b['allowance']] = 0;
    }

  }

// Looping through employees
while($r = $q->fetch_assoc()){

 $id= $r['id'];
 $name= $r['name'];

 $all2 = "select * from emp_allowances order by allowance asc";
 $c = $dbhandle->query($all2);
  if($c->num_rows>0){
    $tdallow='';

    // Looping through employee allowances
    while($d = $c->fetch_assoc()){
      $empid = $d['emp_id'];
      $amount = $d['amount'];
      $empallowance = $d['allowance'];

      if($empid==$id){
        $tdarray[$empallowance] = $amount;
      }
  }
 }  
    $tbody .= '<tr>';
    $tbody .= '<td>'.$name.'</td>';
    foreach ($tdarray as $allowance => $amount) {
      $tbody .= '<td>'.$amount.'</td>';
      // reset to zero 
      $tdarray[$allowance] = 0;
    }
    $tbody .= '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: yes thank you,  i need output like this, but in your $tdarray you define clothing, meal and transportation. i need it to be dynamic and  should depend whatever i have in my database. And inline it with the amount. Sorry im a complete beginner.

Comment: @saitama I edited the code, try it now. Let me know if works or if you need explanation.

Comment: only one thing, im actually retrieving a lot of data and it take some time to load the page, but i guess it's only normal since we're using  more than 1 loop. thanks again, this really help.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `else` with your code:

```
if($empid==$id){
     $tdallow.='<td>'.$amount.'</td>';
}else{ // add else block for print zero
     $tdallow.='<td>0</td>';
}
```